# How do I move the GNOME application launcher to the top?

Tags: gnome

This may sound a bit stupid, but I want my GNOME application launcher at the top (akin to Unity), is there any way to do it?

(Also, how do I change my Windows key to open the application menu instead of Activities view?)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Not sure it's possible to move the dock to the top of the screen but you can position it to the bottom using the routines set out [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-dock-panel-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean moving the icon that opens the application dashboard to the top of the panel?

You should be able to do it using the following command in terminal to set the proper gsetting key:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
```

About the windows key, maybe try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443314/68922 ?

Comment: Yeah. This works for me tysm